# Transform easing functions into moving objects on canvas?

Tags: function, animation, canvas

I am trying to use these easing functions from this page;

https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294

In my canvas project, I am wondering if anyone could shed some light on how to use these with say a rectangle on my canvas which has an x and y property.

I understand `t` is time, (I have successfully managed to get the delta time of my frame intervals, not sure if this is needed).

How can I use these functions to make the easing effects be applied to my rectangle which has an `x` and `y` property which are the co-ordinates of where it should be placed onto the canvas?

I know this question is kinda vague, but I really do not understand these functions and how they should be integrated with a rectangle on the canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this -

([Click here to see working example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/UMqD2/))

```
var x = 100; //final position
var t = 0;   //0-1, this is what you change in animation loop
```

In your loop:

```
function myLoop() {

    var tx = EasingFunctions.easeInQuad(t) * x;    

    // set element by tx

    if (t < 1) {
        t += 0.1; //determines speed
        requestAnimationFrame(myLoop);
        //setTimeout(myLoop, 16); //option to above
    }
}
```

See also:
http://greweb.me/2012/02/bezier-curve-based-easing-functions-from-concept-to-implementation/

Comment: I appreciate this post is old but the jsFiddle doesn't work, the "see also" link doesn't work and the solution given creates nothing more than an unused variable "tx".

Answer (score 1):

I know it's nice to write you own code; but should you want to use a library then this one is pretty good:

[Tween JS](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/)

It uses the easing methods you referenced as supports chaining.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I struggle to use a library to its full extent until I fundamentally know what it is doing and how it is doing it. For production I would use tween js, but I am just trying to learn a bit at the minute, thanks mate.